# Select Layer By Attribute_management not taking variable

Tags: arcpy, arcmap, select-by-attribute

I am trying to make SelectLayerByAttribute_management to take a string (that is an input variable) as the "where_clause". The string would be inputted by the user. If I just put the text I need "29-65-12-3" for example it works but this is a fixed location. I need it to take my previously entered variable. I get all sorts of errors, I tried all combinations.

EDIT: New code works great, it also selects the Coordinate System based on the last character of the string (Meridian 1-6) and it breaks the zoom cycle if the string is not selected from the feature class.

New Code:

```py
import arcpy

mxd = arcpy.mapping.MapDocument('CURRENT')
df = arcpy.mapping.ListDataFrames(mxd, "*") [0]

user_scale = arcpy.GetParameterAsText(0)
location = str(arcpy.GetParameterAsText(1))

UTMS = ['2', '3', '4', '5', '6']

last_char = location[-1]
if last_char not in UTMS:
   sys.exit()

arcpy.SelectLayerByAttribute_management("Section", "CLEAR_SELECTION")

field = arcpy.AddFieldDelimiters("Section", "LABEL")
where_clause = "{field} = '{location}'".format(field=field, location=location)

arcpy.SelectLayerByAttribute_management("Section", "NEW_SELECTION", where_clause)

Num = str(arcpy.GetCount_management("Section"))
if Num == "0":
   arcpy.AddMessage("\n WRONG SEC-TWP-RGE-MER ENTERED! RUN TOOL AGAIN!" + "\n LEGAL LAND LOCATION YOU ENTERED IS: " + location + "\n")
   sys.exit()

df.zoomToSelectedFeatures()

df.scale = user_scale

sr = arcpy.SpatialReference(26912)

UTM11 = ['5', '6']
UTM12 = ['3', '4']
UTM13 = ['2']
if last_char in UTM12:
   sr = arcpy.SpatialReference(26912)
elif last_char in UTM11:
   sr = arcpy.SpatialReference(26911)
else:
   sr = arcpy.SpatialReference(26913)

df.rotation = 0
df.spatialReference = sr

arcpy.RefreshActiveView()

for fc in df:
    arcpy.AddMessage("{0} : {1}".format(fc, sr.name))

cs_message = ("{0} : {1}".format(df, sr.name))

arcpy.AddMessage("\nLegal Land Location you entered is: " + location)
arcpy.AddMessage("Meridian entered is: " + last_char)
arcpy.AddMessage("Coordinate System is: " + cs_message)
arcpy.AddMessage("\nALL DONE!" + "\n")
```

Comment: Please see this advice on writing a [code snippet](http://meta.gis.stackexchange.com/questions/4312) to present here, particularly when it comes to using try/except statements.

Comment: What happens when you run the code that you have presented without any try/except statements?

Comment: `user_scale` and `location` are set by a single parameter, is that your intention? Also your where clause in syntactically incorrect, suggest you review the help file for code samples to guide you.

Comment: You have a choice of learning how to use triple-quotes in a string parameter, using `str.format()`, or both. Lots of examples in the documentation...

Comment: You said that you get "all sorts of errors", but you forgot to include them in your post!  Please edit the post and include the full error stack (not just one line of the errors).  Delete all of the try/except lines, and then what error(s) do you get? (Again, update your post with this information.)

Answer (score 0):

The `where_clause` in the `arcpy.SelectLayerByAttribute_management()` function should be a string.  `"LABEL" == location` is not a string, it is a boolean (probably withe the literal value `False`).  Furthermore, "==" is not the correct comparator to use in SQL (and the `where_clause` is an SQL string, not Python - as far as Python is concerned, it's just a string).

There are a few different ways to include a variable's value as part of a string.  My preferred way is to use the string `format()` function, so...

Replace this:

```
arcpy.SelectLayerByAttribute_management("Section", "NEW_SELECTION", "LABEL" == location)
```

with this:

```
arcpy.SelectLayerByAttribute_management("Section", "NEW_SELECTION", "LABEL = '{}'".format(location))
```

NB:  You may need to use different field/value delimeters in the `where_clause` depending on the database or file type that you're using, as some of them use different SQL variants.

For more information on the `format()` function for strings, see:
https://docs.python.org/3/tutorial/inputoutput.html#the-string-format-method
https://www.w3schools.com/python/ref_string_format.asp

Comment: Thanks very much, I'll give it a try.

Comment: Tried it but won't work, it zooms to the full extent of the feature class (polygons). LABEL is a field in that feature class that needs to be equal to the "location" variable inputted by the user. "29-51-7-5' is an example. If I insert this exact string (instead of "LABEL = '{}'".format(location)) it zooms where it should.

Comment: What data format is the layer in?  Eg Shapefil, file geodatabase, other?  Please post the full error stack that you get after you made the change (update the original post to add the changes to the code AND the error text - all of it)

Comment: The layer is in ESRI shapefile format. I have this now:                   
 where_clause = "LABEL" + '=' + "\'location\'"
arcpy.SelectLayerByAttribute_management("Section", "NEW_SELECTION", where_clause)    It just zooms to the full extent of the layer, no error. I will update the whole post shortly.

Comment: That does not include any variable interpolation to the string.  That is exactly the same as doing this:  `"LABEL = 'location'"`.  It includes the actual text "location", but you don't want that.  You need to use the value of the `location` variable.  Not the string "location".

Comment: I managed to make it work just like I wanted. It also checks if a selection was made and if not it breaks the zoom cycle. It also selects the Coordinate System based on the last character of the string (Meridian 1-6). Thanks so much all. I'll edit the post for the new code.

Comment: If the problem is fixed, please post the fix to a new answer post, NOT to the original question.

Comment: Thanks, I will move it in the answer post. The script works exactly how it's inteded, however, it looks like it's causing some memory problems, when I resize the ArcMap window it doesn't refresh the workspace properly and when I export JPEG based on the window size (trying to crop by resizing the ArcMap window or Catalog window) it exports ignoring this. If I don't use the code when first opening the MXD ArcMap behaves normally. Could it be any garbage left in the memory? Any way to clear anything the code left there after executing it? Thanks again...

Comment: Sounds like you will need to post a new question for this one, if you haven't already resolved it.